# XCode gives an error with C++ templates

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, templates

When I'm using custom templates, that work in VS2010, I get an error.
It's obviously because the systems are different, but how can I make XCode read the templates? 
Here's the templates file:

```
#ifndef TEMPLATE_H_INCLUDED
#define TEMPLATE_H_INCLUDED
#include <algorithm>
#include <math.h>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>        // std::abs
#include <float.h>

using namespace std;

namespace Geometry
{

    #if _MSC_VER // this is defined when compiling with Visual Studio
        #define M_PI 3.14159265358979f
    #endif
        #define Deg2Rad(deg)  ((deg) * M_PI / 180)

        #define Rad2Deg(rad)  ((rad) * 180 / M_PI)

        template <typename T> int sgn(T val)
        { return (T(0) < val) - (val < T(0)); }

        template <typename T> bool isnan (T value)
        { return value != value; }

        template <typename T> T Clamp(const T& value, const T& low, const T& high)
        {
          return value < low ? low : (value > high ? high : value);
        }
        template <typename T> T Clamp01(const T& value)
        {
          return value < 0 ? 0 : (value > 1 ? 1 : value);
        }
        /// Return the real part of the square root of x.
        inline float fsqrtf (float x)
        { return x > 0.0f ? std::sqrt (x) : 0.0f; }

};
```

What I'm doing with this header, is quite simple.
I simply include the header and start using the templates.
They work in VS2010 but they don't in XCode, so how can I solve this issue?
I also am using namespace Geometry in the start of the cpp file.

Here's the error message:

```
 No matching function for call to 'Clamp'
```

As Requested by JBL, heres the code:

```
#include "templates.h"
using namespace Geometry;

class Curve
{
    public:
        GetClampedValue(float value);
};

#include "myclass.h"
void MyClass::GetClampedValue(float value)
{
    return Clamp(value,-1,1);// Error Here
}
```

Comment: Could you post the relevant code?

Comment: Excuse me but what is there to post? The usage is quite simple value = clamp(something,min,max). I simply would like to know, what do I have to do, to use regular templates in XCode, every programmer with some basic knowledge should know that. Seeing that I get downvotes on a quite simple question I'm not quite up to sharing code to a community where questions remain unsolved. Sorry.

Comment: If you don't give us the tools to help you, that's going to be hard. And as such, it's on hold. Post the code where you call it. Even a "quite simple usage" like `clamp(something,min,max)` can fail to compile. It's completely up to you if you want help.

Comment: Updated my post to suit the requirements.

Answer (score 1):

And there it is. The code you posted cannot compile as it is currently.

Indeed, the signature of your templated function is `T(const T&, const T&, const T&)` which means the three arguments must share the same type., but you pass a `float` and two `int`s.
Clang will give you a nice error message about that:

> candidate template ignored: deduced conflicting types for parameter 'T' ('float' vs. 'int')

Either use arguments that share the same type, or change the template arguments so that it may accepts different types, i.e.

```
template<typename T, typename U, typename V>
T (const T&, const U&, const V&)
{...}
```

You can even use type traits if you want to force types to have some properties (e.g. `std::is_arithmetic`).